# Remove Duplicates in a SQL Select

Tags: sql, mariadb

Have a table contact tracing duration between userid & contactid.

1. Want to sum the duration of all contacts between uid & cid.
2. There will always have 2 rows for each contact A&B, B&A.

select * from tracing

| uid | cid | dura |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 5min |
| A | B | 1min |
| B | A | 5min |
| B | A | 1min |
| B | C | 2min |
| C | B | 2min |

select uid, cid, sum(dura) as total from tracing group by uid, cid order by total desc

| uid | cid | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 6min |
| B | A | 6min |
| B | C | 2min |
| C | B | 2min |

Result wanted is

| uid | cid | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 6min |
| B | C | 2min |

As contact between A&B is the same as B&A, I want to select only 1 result A&B.
How do I use select or subqueries, Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want to filter your results:

```
select uid, cid, sum(dura) as total
from tracking
where uid = 'A'
group by userid, contactid 
order by by total desc;
```

Note:  Standard SQL doesn't have a `SORT BY` clause (although some databases do support this).  The standard is `ORDER BY`.

EDIT:

For the edited question, you seem to want:

```
select uid, cid, sum(dura) as total
from tracking
group by userid < contactid 
order by by total desc;
```

Comment: Sorry, question wasnt clear enought, edited.

Comment: 1. Want to sum the duration of all contacts between uid & cid.
2. There will always have 2 rows for each contact A&B, B&A.  
As contact between A&B is the same as B&A, I want to select only 1 result A&B.

Comment: @Tiketgcp . . . Did you see the edited query?